# Problems with install_bitbucket

Tags: r, r-devtools

I have a student in my class who has had problems installing the course R package which is on bitbucket. He is running Windows Version 8, 64 bit. I tried to install directly from the package tar ball using RStudio|Tools|Install Packages and got the same error. He does not have Rtools installed but I don't see how this is related to this.

It seems that R CMD install is creating a batch file with the `C:\Program Files ...` in it and the space is causing problems.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

p rossi

```
> install_bitbucket("DataAnalyticsV1.0.0","perossichi")

Installing bitbucket repo(s) DataAnalyticsV1.0.0/master from perossichi
Downloading master.zip from https://bitbucket.org/perossichi/dataanalyticsv1.0.0/get/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\crist_000\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6daA6F/master.zip
Installing DataAnalytics
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
"C:\Users\crist_000\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6daA6F\devtools49e4748d6bfe\perossichi-         dataanalyticsv1.0.0-84a47dab91db"  \
 --library="C:/Users/crist_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.0" --install-tests

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252  
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Chile.1252   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.1 httr_0.2       memoise_0.1    parallel_3.0.2
[6] RCurl_1.95-4.1 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2    whisker_0.3-2
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall R
2. Re-install R in the root folder like `C:\` instead of `C:\Program Files\`

Reference:
https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/333#issuecomment-32733936

The weird thing is this bug is not specific to devtools.  Drag R.EXE from Windows Explorer to a CMD.EXE window (which pastes its path there), and you get the same error.  It does not happen for RCMD.EXE.  Tested with R 3.1.2 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @bummi OK, I added it here